# z-index and position for multiple div

Tags: html, css

I have been messing with z-index and position properties trying to achieve the div box setup below. what's position should I be using and the max z-index readable by all devices including mobile should be 99 right? my z-index seem to be way off.

```
<div style="width: 990px; border: 1px solid;">
  <div style="z-index: 1; border: 1px solid; background: #000; position:absolute;">
    Top div 1
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: -2; border: 1px solid; background: #000; position:absolute;">
    back div 2
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: -1; border: 1px solid; background: #000; position:absolute;">
    back div 3
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: 2; border: 1px solid; background: #000; position:absolute;">
    text div 4
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: 3; border: 1px solid; background: #000; position:absolute;">
    Top div 5
  </div>
  <div style="z-index: -1; border: 1px solid; background: #000; position:absolute;">
    Top div 6
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You could do what you have designed above with z-indexes of 1 through 6.  The max valid z-index appears to have practically no limit.  I regularly use 50000 to ensure an element will show on top of all other elements (in WP installs, where sometimes there's other's code, not just my one, to contend with)

Comment: Why do you believe they should layout that way? They all have `display: absolute` so I'd think they should all be on top of each other. This jsfiddle agrees. http://jsfiddle.net/tmkYD/ Are you missing some `left` and `top` properties?

Comment: If you have position absolute you have to give them top and left values for them not to be stacked on top of each other

Comment: `z-index` is interpreted by the browser as a signed integer, therefore the range is `–2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

Comment: Shouldn't the outermost div have position:relative, as well?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh they div's represent images of a design that was not created by me.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Can you point to a source for that number? The W3C seems to be intentionally vague about what the range of z-index numbers can be.

Comment: @cale_b And how can you be sure that those "other's code" only use z-indexes lower than 50000?

Comment: @MrLister - can't.  Just a best effort attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The very back ones and textdiv, could be floating divs, to `left`, `left` and `right` respectively, adjusting only their margins.

The ones that should be over the others (top, back and top) could be wrapped in a `position:absolute` div and be all `position:relative` to it. There, again, should play with their margins and set a high `z-index`, like `z-index:1000` to assure you they should be on top.

This way is more simple than trying to deal with them separately.

Hope this helps.
Cheers